# MongoDB / Morphia - Delete object not behaving properly, what did I miss?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia, nosql

I have query for deletion like so:

```
Query<E> query = datastore.createQuery(entityClass);
query.field(fieldName).equals(fieldValue);
return datastore.findAndDelete(query);
```

So the intent is to select an object based on an unique field and have it deleted. I have four objects in the collection, each with a different value for the field I'm querying by. But when I perform the `findAndDelete` a random object is deleted returned, not the one matching the criteria.

I execute this over and over and each time another random object is returned, until all are deleted and then it returns `null`.

I'm essentially executing this:

```
Query<Entity> query = datastore.createQuery(Entity.class);
query.field("uniqueHash").equals("SDFSDGRTGEFQDFRYDGSWE");
return datastore.findAndDelete(query);
```

And when I debug I see that all objects in the collections actually have different values for the `uniqueHash` field

What am I missing?? Am I not building this query correctly?

**UPDATE: ** Here is the complete data before and after the delete operation:

```
> db.CustomObject.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a590546c66e6672cfff53a"),
        "className" : "com.test.CustomObject",
        "tokenHash" : "SG6o3mXOOBfGHYlhA2S2p52O1/GXOUZvF6kY5X3ZyvA="
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a590546c66e6672cfff53b"),
        "className" : "com.test.CustomObject",
        "tokenHash" : "RotU72A4E9Oh8qC+cCX4Y+MdIShuuaDX03jQQXZVG34="
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a590546c66e6672cfff53c"),
        "className" : "com.test.CustomObject",
        "tokenHash" : "sYLKPRlddqc3I+ORVwCzYjzeU+ErBveQNvHYYyCsi7o="
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a590546c66e6672cfff53d"),
        "className" : "com.test.CustomObject",
        "tokenHash" : "eVltEP/ptPqw6WrMDCCzd+rcoVrShcMr9fF3CENLj8Q="
}
```

Then I execute:

```
Query<CustomObject> query = datastore.createQuery(CustomObject.class);
query.field("tokenHash").equals("RotU72A4E9Oh8qC+cCX4Y+MdIShuuaDX03jQQXZVG34=");
return datastore.findAndDelete(query);
```

And the result is that an object was deleted, but not the one I was hoping for:

```
> db.CustomObject.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a590546c66e6672cfff53b"),
        "className" : "com.test.CustomObject",
        "tokenHash" : "RotU72A4E9Oh8qC+cCX4Y+MdIShuuaDX03jQQXZVG34="
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a590546c66e6672cfff53c"),
        "className" : "com.test.CustomObject",
        "tokenHash" : "sYLKPRlddqc3I+ORVwCzYjzeU+ErBveQNvHYYyCsi7o="
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a590546c66e6672cfff53d"),
        "className" : "com.test.CustomObject",
        "tokenHash" : "eVltEP/ptPqw6WrMDCCzd+rcoVrShcMr9fF3CENLj8Q="
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the four records from the collection, that you are trying to delete?

Comment: Absolutely! I added the full data before the query, then the query, and the result after the deletion. Thank you for looking into it! :D

Comment: Can you try this - `datastore.createQuery(CustomObject.class).field("tokenHash").equal(value);`, The only problem i see is your query condition not being met. The document says to use `equal`. `equals` is a method of the `Object` class, and the statement just returns true or false, without actually setting the search criteria.

Comment: Duuude, you found it! That was it, I didn't notice I was using the wrong method!! Thank you!! You might want post it as an answer so I accept it (and you get the rep :D).

Comment: Have posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Field` class' `equal` method instead of the `equals` method of the `Object` class.

```
query.field("tokenHash").equal("RotU72A4E9Oh8qC+cCX4Y+MdIShuuaDX03jQQXZVG34=");
```

`equals` is a method in the `Object` class used for comparing the value in two Objects. It returns just true or false. Hence the below statement

```
query.field("tokenHash").equals("RotU72A4E9Oh8qC+cCX4Y+MdIShuuaDX03jQQXZVG34=");
```

Would return `false`, without actually building an `query` object which the `equal` method of the `Field` class does.